# Centering my textView inside imageView relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm attempting to center my textView inside an imageView to the right of the screen in the middle. The issue I'm having is it's showing up to the left slightly rather then centering ontop of the imageView. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="69dp"
           android:layout_height="22dp"
           android:src="@drawable/price_bubble" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView_price"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

     </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use padding left android:paddingLeft ="10dp"

Comment: I actually just tried changing the android:layout_gravity on the textview to center instead of center_vertical, and that seemed to fix it, for now!

Comment: Why are you using `ImageView`? Just use `price_bubble drawable` as background of `FrameLayout` and only `TextView` Also layout_gravity cenre_vertical keeps your TextView on `Left Center` so instead of that use only `center`. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="69dp"
           android:layout_height="22dp"
           android:src="@drawable/price_bubble" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView_price"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center" />

     </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your imageview image is having some transparent padding thats why it is happening.